# Alerts on Color changes

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to just get alert when color change of the line. This code alerts at each bar which I don't want.

```
study("Tillson T3", overlay=true)
length1 = input(8, "T3 Length")
a1 = input(0.7, "Volume Factor")

e1=ema((high + low + 2*close)/4, length1)
e2=ema(e1,length1)
e3=ema(e2,length1)
e4=ema(e3,length1)
e5=ema(e4,length1)
e6=ema(e5,length1)
c1=-a1*a1*a1
c2=3*a1*a1+3*a1*a1*a1
c3=-6*a1*a1-3*a1-3*a1*a1*a1
c4=1+3*a1+a1*a1*a1+3*a1*a1
T3=c1*e6+c2*e5+c3*e4+c4*e3

col1= T3>T3[1]
col3= T3<T3[1]
color = col1 ? green : col3 ? red : yellow
plot(T3, color=color, linewidth=3, title="T3")

alertcondition(col1, title='Alert on Green Bar', message='Green Bar!')
alertcondition(col3, title='Alert on Red Bar', message='Red Bar!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as long as `condition` argument of the `alertcondition()` is `true`, you will get an alert.

If you plot `col1` and `col3`, you will see why you are getting multiple alerts. It is because one of them stays `true` for multiple bars. What you need is a **pulse**.

[image]

To create a pulse, you need to think about your implementation. Your implementation guarantees that `col1` and `col3` can never be `true` at the same time. So, you can compare `col3[1]` and `col1`. So that, if `col3[1] and col1` is true, it means that one bar ago `col3` was true, but for the current bar only `col1` is true, which indicates a change from `col3` to `col1`.

Have a look at the following code and chart:

```
//@version=3
study(title="Color", overlay=false)
T3 = close
col1= T3>T3[1]
col3= T3<T3[1]
isNewCol1 = nz(col3[1]) and col1
isNewCol3 = nz(col1[1]) and col3

plot(series=isNewCol1 ? 1 : 0, title="isNewCol1", color=orange, linewidth=4)
plot(series=isNewCol3 ? 1 : 0, title="isNewCol3", color=blue, linewidth=4)
```

[image]

### **Edit**:

You just need to use those variables in `alertcondition()`.

```
study("Tillson T3", overlay=true)
length1 = input(8, "T3 Length")
a1 = input(0.7, "Volume Factor")

e1=ema((high + low + 2*close)/4, length1)
e2=ema(e1,length1)
e3=ema(e2,length1)
e4=ema(e3,length1)
e5=ema(e4,length1)
e6=ema(e5,length1)
c1=-a1*a1*a1
c2=3*a1*a1+3*a1*a1*a1
c3=-6*a1*a1-3*a1-3*a1*a1*a1
c4=1+3*a1+a1*a1*a1+3*a1*a1
T3=c1*e6+c2*e5+c3*e4+c4*e3

col1= T3>T3[1]
col3= T3<T3[1]
isNewCol1 = nz(col3[1]) and col1
isNewCol3 = nz(col1[1]) and col3
colorP = col1 ? green : col3 ? red : yellow
plot(T3, color=colorP, linewidth=3, title="T3")

plotshape(series=isNewCol1, title="col1", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, text="Green", size=size.normal)
plotshape(series=isNewCol3, title="col3", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=red, text="Red", size=size.normal)
alertcondition(condition=isNewCol1, title="isNewCol1", message="green")
alertcondition(condition=isNewCol3, title="isNewCol3", message="red")
```

[image]

Comment: this is not actualy What I'm trying to achieve . I updated my orginal code now.

Comment: Well, it is kinda what you are trying to achieve. I told you why you are having issues and how to solve them. You just need to apply `isNewCol1` and `isNewCol3` to `condition` of the `alertcondition()`. See my updated answer, I used `plotshape()` for simplicity. It only plots arrows when the color changes (not for every bar). So, it will only throw alerts where you see arrows on the chart.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
buy= T3>T3[1] and T3[1]<T3[2] 
sell= T3<T3[1] and T3[1]>T3[2]  
color = T3>T3[1] ? green : T3<T3[1] ? red : yellow
plot(T3, color=color, linewidth=3, title="T3")
alertcondition(buy, title='Alert on Green Bar', message='Green Bar!')
alertcondition(sell, title='Alert on Red Bar', message='Red Bar!')
```